# Como criar uma função igual a Array.Copy do C# no C++

Tags: c#, c++, array

Gostaria de criar uma função parecida com a `Array.Copy` do C# no C++.

Essa função tem o protótipo assim:

```
public static void Copy(
    Array sourceArray,
    int sourceIndex,
    Array destinationArray,
    int destinationIndex,
    int length
);
```

E gostaria de fazer uma função que fizesse a mesma função em C++.

Eu tentei fazer utilizando um `for`, porém não consegui fazer funcionar com o `destinationIndex`.

Meu código:

```
template <T> void Buffer <T> ::copy(T * src, int indexSrc, T * dst, int indexDst, int elements) {
    for (int srcAux = indexSrc, dstAux = indexDst, int aux = 0; aux != elements; srcAux++, dstAux++, aux++) {
        dst[indexDst] = src[srcAux];
    }
}
```

Comment: Poste o que você já fez.

Comment: Minha função ficou assim: 
`template<T>
void Buffer<T>::copy(T *src, int indexSrc, T *dst, int indexDst, int elements){
    for(int srcAux = indexSrc, dstAux = indexDst, int aux = 0;aux != elements;srcAux++, dstAux++, aux++){
        dst[indexDst] = src[srcAux];
    }
}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O C++ já tem algo pronto que faz isto com [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
std::copy(std::begin(src), std::end(src), std::begin(dest));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/CopyFunction.cpp).

Tentar traduzir o código de uma linguagem para outra sem entender a linguagem não dá certo. Cada linguagem tem sua especificidade e jeito de fazer cada operação.

Nossa *tag* [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tem informações de como começar aprender C++.